# Is it cold or hot on top of a tropical cyclone?

Tags: temperature, clouds, tropical-cyclone

So I know that cloud tops of the thunderstorm in a tropical cyclone can reach -80 degrees Celsius according to infrared satellite imagery. Is the temperature of the air above the storm's eyewall different from the cloud top temperature?

I saw [this diagram](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Guido-Cioni/publication/301790577/figure/fig1/AS:357634168377353@1462278038980/The-Hurricane-Carnot-cycle-the-colors-depict-entropy-distribution-blue-green.png) which shows the carnot cycle inside a tropical cyclone. Point B to C is the adiabatic expansion part while C to D is the isothermal compression part. It seems that, from the diagram, the -75 degrees Celsius area is only from point C to D. The area above the eyewall seems very warm due to the latent heat release from the condensation of water vapor.

Or is the chart showing equivalent potential temperature? Does that mean the temperature above the eyewall is still around -75 degrees Celsius? All the temperature profiles I've seen of a tropical cyclone uses equivalent potential temperature and not actual temperature.